# Spring multi tenancy : Add a data source to MultiTenantConnectionProvider dynamically when a user is added

Tags: java, spring, multi-tenant

I have a scenario wherein a user signs up and a new database is created for them. This database needs to be added to the MultiTenantConnectionProvider (connection pool) as soon as the sign up process is completed. Everything is working just fine but am not able to add the data source dynamically to the MultiTenantConnectionProvider.

Hibernate config for multitenancy:

```
       <property name="hibernateProperties">
            <props>
                <prop key="hibernate.dialect">org.hibernate.dialect.MySQLDialect</prop>
                <prop key="hibernate.multiTenancy">DATABASE</prop>
                <prop key="hibernate.tenant_identifier_resolver">com.company.multitenancy.MyCurrentTenantIdentifierResolverImpl
                </prop>
                <prop key="hibernate.multi_tenant_connection_provider">com.company.multitenancy.MyMultiTenantConnectionProvider
                </prop>
            </props>
        </property>
```

Code for MyMultiTenantConnectionProvider :

```
package com.company.multitenancy;

import java.sql.DriverManager;
import java.sql.ResultSet;
import java.sql.Statement;
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.HashMap;
import java.util.List;

import org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.connections.spi.AbstractMultiTenantConnectionProvider;
import org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.connections.spi.ConnectionProvider;    
import com.termbreak.constant.ConstantStrings;

public class MyMultiTenantConnectionProvider extends
        AbstractMultiTenantConnectionProvider {
    private static final long serialVersionUID = -8669630427906544663L;
    private HashMap<String, ConnectionProviderImpl> connProviderMap = new HashMap<String, ConnectionProviderImpl>();

    public MyMultiTenantConnectionProvider() {
        List<String> providerNames = new ArrayList<String>();
        providerNames.add(ConstantStrings.DEFAULT_TENANT_ID);
        try {
            String sqlUrl = "jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/"+ConstantStrings.DEFAULT_TENANT_ID;
            Class.forName("com.mysql.jdbc.Driver");
            java.sql.Connection conn = DriverManager.getConnection(sqlUrl,
                    "root", "root");
            Statement st = conn.createStatement();
            ResultSet rs = st
                    .executeQuery("select DISTINCT TENANT_ID from User");
            while (rs.next()) {
                String tenantId = rs.getString(1);
                providerNames.add(tenantId);
            }
            conn.close();
        } catch (Exception e) {
            System.err.println("Got an exception! ");
            System.err.println(e.getMessage());
        }
        for (String providerName : providerNames) {
            connProviderMap.put(providerName, new ConnectionProviderImpl(
                    providerName));
        }
    }

    public ConnectionProvider getAnyConnectionProvider() {
        System.out
                .println("inside MultiTenantConnectionProvider::getAnyConnectionProvider");
        return connProviderMap.get(ConstantStrings.DEFAULT_TENANT_ID);
    }

    public ConnectionProvider selectConnectionProvider(String tenantId) {
        ConnectionProvider connectionProvider = connProviderMap.get(tenantId);
        if (connectionProvider == null)
            connectionProvider = new ConnectionProviderImpl(ConstantStrings.DEFAULT_TENANT_ID);
        return connectionProvider;
    }
}
```

Code for MyCurrentTenantIdResolver :

```
package com.company.multitenancy;

import org.hibernate.context.spi.CurrentTenantIdentifierResolver;

import com.termbreak.constant.ConstantStrings;

public class MyCurrentTenantIdentifierResolverImpl implements
        CurrentTenantIdentifierResolver {
    public ThreadLocal<String> _tenantIdentifier = new ThreadLocal<String>();
    public String DEFAULT_TENANT_ID = ConstantStrings.DEFAULT_TENANT_ID;

    public String resolveCurrentTenantIdentifier() {
        System.out.println("from inside resolveCurrentTenantIdentifier....");
        String tenantId = _tenantIdentifier.get();
        if (tenantId == null)
            tenantId = DEFAULT_TENANT_ID;
        System.out.println("threadlocal tenant id =" + tenantId);
        return tenantId;
    }

    public boolean validateExistingCurrentSessions() {
        return true;
    }

}
```

Code for MyConnectionProviderImpl :

```
package com.company.multitenancy;

import java.sql.Connection;
import java.sql.SQLException;

import org.apache.commons.dbcp2.BasicDataSource;
import org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.connections.spi.ConnectionProvider;

public class ConnectionProviderImpl implements ConnectionProvider { 
    private static final long serialVersionUID = -8926112316994338537L;
    private BasicDataSource basicDataSource;

    public ConnectionProviderImpl(String database){
        //this should be read from properties file
        basicDataSource = new BasicDataSource();
        basicDataSource.setDriverClassName("com.mysql.jdbc.Driver");
        basicDataSource.setUrl("jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/"+database);
        basicDataSource.setUsername("root");
        basicDataSource.setPassword("root");
        basicDataSource.setInitialSize(2);
    }
    public boolean isUnwrappableAs(Class arg0) {
        return false;
    }
    public Object unwrap(Class arg0) {
        return null;
    }
    public void closeConnection(Connection arg0) throws SQLException {
        arg0.close();
    }
    public Connection getConnection() throws SQLException {
        return basicDataSource.getConnection();
    }
    public boolean supportsAggressiveRelease() {
        return false;
    }
}
```

To connect to particular tenant i am using :

```
sessionFactory.withOptions().tenantIdentifier(tenantId).openSession();
```

Answer (score 1):

Your configuration seems to be correct except implementation of ConnectionProviderImpl. In this implementation, you need to provide hibernate with tenant identifier. You would require to implement AbstractDataSourceBasedMultiTenantConnectionProviderImpl and either override getConnection() or selectDataSource() depending upon Hibernate version you are using. I would suggest you to follow Hibernate user guide https://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/orm/4.3/devguide/en-US/html/ch16.html example 16.3 and this post http://www.ticnfae.co.uk/blog/2014/07/16/hibernate-multi-tenancy-with-spring/.

Comment: thanks for your quick reply, every thing is working perfect with this code the only problem i am facing right now is when a user signs up a new database is created for that user and a new tenant id is generated i need to add this tenant id to the connection pool which i am not able to. any pointers will help

Comment: Instead of directly implementing ConnectionProvider, can you try by extending AbstractDataSourceBasedMultiTenantConnectionProviderImpl and override selectDataSource(). MyCurrentTenantIdentifierResolverImpl#resolveCurrentTenantIdentifier() returns tenant identifier. This tenant identifier is used in AbstractDataSourceBasedMultiTenantConnectionProviderImpl#selectDataSource(String tenantIdentifier).